# How to fix disabled form fields in Magento customer create account page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, magento

I took over a half finished Magento store from a developer and for some reason, the form fields in the create account page are disabled.

I tried figuring out why this happened but can't seem to find the issue, in the console everything looks fine but isn't...

Here's the page http://www.allinsafety.com/index.php/customer/account/create/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Enable below css for input box. this will related to font and showing disable in your site as per below screenshot(css mark with color in screenshot).

```
font: 13.3333px Arial;
```

[image]